# Multiple grids on a single page

Tags: php, mysql, grid

Im wanting to list two grids on a single page... Problem is when clicking the add record button both sql tables that the grids reference are updated with the same record being updated.
How can I set things up so that only the relevant table is updated?

Using the following class found at: http://lazymofo.wdschools.com/

Answer (score 0):

This class is not designed to have multiple grids on a single page. Possibly in the future this feature could be added. For now your only option is to use frames/iframes.